# Unable to run github cli in interactive mode

Tags: github, github-cli

I am trying to create a repo using GitHub cli the command that I've used is `gh repo create <repo name>` but I am getting the following error

```
--public`, `--private`, or `--internal` required when not running interactively

Usage:  gh repo create [<name>] [flags]
```

I can use flags and make it work but I want to use interactive mode it should work interactively out of the box but not working

Comment: To fall back to interactive mode, you must not provide a repository name, just `gh repo create`.

Comment: thanks my bad that was silly

Answer (score 0):

If you run the `gh repo create` command without using the `<repo name>` it will run interactively.

Answer (score 0):

just write the below command on GitHub CLI and it will start in interactive mode to create the repositories

> gh repo create